# Custom Tkinter - duplication after pack_forget

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I have a frame with two labels, two combo boxes, and a button. The button should, when pressed add another row of combo boxes to the frame.

[image]

When I press it, it adds two more combo boxes, but also a second AddButton which seems to have no functionality...

[image]

I use pack_forget to remove the whole frame and recreate it with the extra combo boxes, so I have zero clue where the second plus button comes from.

Here is the full code I'm using:

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('dark-blue') #dark-blue, blue, or green


def loadSelectionFrame(buttonCount=1):
    selectionFrame.rowconfigure(buttonCount+2, weight=1)
    selectionFrame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    selectionFrame.pack()

    fieldLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=selectionFrame, text="Choose Field")
    fieldLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=12, padx=10)
    typeLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=selectionFrame, text="Choose Value")
    typeLabel.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=12, padx=10)
    for i in range(buttonCount):
        fieldsDropDown = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=selectionFrame, values=["Option 1", "Option 2"])
        fieldsDropDown.grid(row=i+2, column=1, pady=12, padx=10)
        typeDropDown = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=selectionFrame, values=["Option 1", "Option 2"])
        typeDropDown.grid(row=i+2, column=2, pady=12, padx=10)
    addMoreFieldsButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=selectionFrame, text="+", command=lambda: addMoreFields(buttonCount+1, selectionFrame))
    addMoreFieldsButton.grid(row=buttonCount+2, columnspan=3, pady=12, padx=10)

def addMoreFields(buttonCount, selectionFrame):
    selectionFrame.pack_forget()
    loadSelectionFrame(buttonCount)
    
root = customtkinter.CTk()
mainFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
mainFrame.pack(pady=20,padx=60, fill='both', expand=True)
selectionFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=mainFrame)

loadSelectionFrame()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well your function  `loadSelectionFrame` creates a `CTkButton` as well as two labels, so when you call it again of course it will add another button. Perhaps move your creation of the `CTkButton` outside of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `selectionFrame.pack_forget()` will only make `selectionFrame` hidden, widgets inside it will not be destroyed.

The simple fix is to destroy those widgets instead:

```py
def addMoreFields(buttonCount, selectionFrame):
    # destroy widgets inside selectionFrame
    for widget in selectionFrame.winfo_children(): widget.destroy()
    loadSelectionFrame(buttonCount)
```

---

However, destroying and recreating those widgets is not a good design.  It is better to just add the two comboboxes when the `+` button is clicked.

Below is the modified code:

```py
import customtkinter
import tkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('dark-blue') #dark-blue, blue, or green

# function to add two comboboxes
def addMoreFields():
    fieldsDropDown = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=selectionFrame, values=["Option 1", "Option 2"])
    fieldsDropDown.grid(column=1, pady=12, padx=10)
    row = fieldsDropDown.grid_info()["row"]
    typeDropDown = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=selectionFrame, values=["Option 1", "Option 2"])
    typeDropDown.grid(row=row, column=2, pady=12, padx=10)

root = customtkinter.CTk()

mainFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
mainFrame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill='both', expand=True)

selectionFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=mainFrame)
selectionFrame.pack()

# headings
fieldLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=selectionFrame, text="Choose Field")
fieldLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=12, padx=10)
typeLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=selectionFrame, text="Choose Value")
typeLabel.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=12, padx=10)

# add button
addMoreFieldsButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="+", command=addMoreFields)
addMoreFieldsButton.pack(pady=12)

addMoreFields() # add first row

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, my main problem was that I thought I had to configure the grid beforehand and could not modify it. Which was why I tried to destroy and rebuild it